# Multiselect Picklist values are not stored in the database as User entered order in UI

Tags: apex, picklist, configuration, multi-select

Requirment : Values should be stored in order as they selected in UI. But Multiselect Picklist values are not stored in the database as User entered order in UI.
Please help us is there any solution or workaround.

I have gone throught this article , but could not solve my problem
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384484&type=1

Picklist Order:
[image]

UI User Entered Order
[image]

UI Saved:
[image]

Query Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the scenarios mentioned in the [help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=000384484&type=1) article, its working as expected.

In your case, you might have created the picklist values in the order below order.

> R-50G-511-MU-R
>
> R-50W-541
>
> R-50G-511
>
> R-50G-516
>
> R-50G-511-MU

After creation of multiselect picklist field, for some reasons you `reorder` the picklist values as like below.

> R-50W-541
>
> R-50G-511
>
> R-50G-511-MU
>
> R-50G-511-MU-R
>
> R-50G-516
>
> R-50G-517

It will show the values in UI as per the `reorder`. Refer the below screenshot `Multiselect_picklist3__c` field.

[image]

When you query data using SOQL you will get values as per the order when created the field.Refer the below screenshot `Multiselect_picklist3__c` field.

[image]

I have created the Multiselect_picklist2__c with below order and didn't `reoder` the picklist values after creation.

> R-50W-541
>
> R-50G-511
>
> R-50G-511-MU
>
> R-50G-511-MU-R
>
> R-50G-516
>
> R-50G-517

Now the picklist values order in the `UI` and `backend` will be the same. Refer the below screenshots of `Multiselect_picklist2__c` field.

[image]
[image]

Conclusion: `If you query the multiselect picklist field using SOQL the result will be displayed as per the order when creation of the field and it will not consider the reorder.`